# Exception using DateTime in a parameterized OleDbCommand

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetime, oledb

I'm trying to insert a System.DateTime into an Access database using a parameterized OleDbCommand in C#. However, it throws a `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` exception.

Here is my code:

```
string statement = "INSERT INTO Log (SCTID, LogDateTime, Type, Message, Visible)" +
    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(statement, connection);

// Add parameters to the command            
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCTID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = SCTID;
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogDateTime", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = dateTime;
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", OleDbType.Integer).Value = (int)logType;
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = message;
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Visible", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = visible;

insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I comment out the `LogDateTime` line, the rest of it works. My problem is that no matter what I use for the DateTime type, it doesn't work. I've tried:

`OleDbType.Date, OleDbType.DBDate, OleDBType.DBTimeStamp, DbType.Date, DbType.DateTime, DbType.DateTime2`

I've also tried:

```
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogDateTime", dateTime);
```

It doesn't work either. Nothing I've read through Google or SO works. Also, note that I do need both date and time, not just a date alone.

Comment: What type is the `LogDateTime` column in the database?

Comment: try converting dateTime to a string.

Comment: What is the type of the column in Access for LogDateTime?

Comment: LogDateTime is a Date/Time in the database.

Comment: What is the value of dateTime? I think .NET and Access have different min and max values.

Comment: The value of dateTime was just a DateTime.Now. In any case, truncating the milliseconds solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCTID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = SCTID;
...
```

That's a very strange way to use `AddWithValue`. Its second parameter is not the type - it's the value that you want it to have. As given, you just end up using the integral value of enumeration member `OleDbType.Integer`, and then immediately overwrite it by assigning to `Value` property. It should be either:

```
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCTID", SCTID);
```

or:

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SCTID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = SCTID;
```

Regarding the statement itself - why do you use `?` for placeholders in command text, but then use names when adding parameters to the collection?

Regarding the actual problem - looks like it's a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94377/oledbparameter-with-dbtype-datetime-throws-data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression), and the workaround is to truncate milliseconds in your `DateTime` value before assigning, and to use `OleDbType.Date`.

Comment: Ah yes, forgive my weird parameters. The first tutorial I found about parameterization did it that way, and although I had an inkling that it was weird, I haven't gotten around to changing them yet. Thanks very much for the tip. Also, I'll give the truncating milliseconds a shot, seems like it might work.