# SQL SELECT query not retrieving rows from a simple Access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

The `DayDate` column in the database is of type `DateTime` & I'm passing a string formulated using a `DateTimePicker` in a form. The `reader.HasRows` always returns false!! I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. The code that I used is below.

```
if (!this.con.IsConnected())
{
   this.con.Connect();
}

this.cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DayNo FROM [Calendar] WHERE DayDate = " + date + "", this.con.conObj());

this.reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
this.reader.Read();

int dayNo;
if (this.reader.HasRows)
{
   dayNo = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
}
else
{
   throw new InfoException("The system could not locate the date in the system");
}
```

Comment: Can you post the value for `date` that your passing into the query? Also can you state more clearly what it is your trying to achieve?

Comment: Also note that you are calling reader.Read() and then calling reader.HasRows. Either call reader.HasRows first in an enclosing if, or use if(reader.Read()) { //do something}. I personally prefer if(reader.Read()) { } as it's fewer lines of code.

Comment: Try if (reader.HasRows && reader.Read()) { reader[0] ETC... }

Comment: I'm actually passing a string for example, something like "12/18/2011". What I'm trying to do is, check if there are any related rows to this specific date. I can easily enter the date but when I try to retrieve the record with this date, it doesn't work. It's as if there are no records with this date. I tried if(reader.Read()) & if(reader.HasRows && reader.Read()) with no luck...

Comment: I solved it. I had to make some small changes in the query. I have to admit I don't actually understand why it didn't work. The working piece of code is this - "SELECT DayNo FROM [Calendar] WHERE DayDate LIKE '" + date + "'", this.con.conObj()" Thank you for your assistance, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Ramila `LIKE` will work because it will match the date portions of each date, however, the underlying problem is your comparing 2 dates incorrectly. See my answer for more info.

Comment: It might be better to also use a parameterised query - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808012/exception-using-datetime-in-a-parameterized-oledbcommand for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your comparing a `Date` value to a `DateTime` so in essence you could possibly be comparing values like this:

```
DayDate = "2011-12-18 14:22:54"
Date = "2011-12-18 00:00:00"
```

You need to truncate the time part from your DB dates, try something like this:

```
"SELECT DayNo FROM [Calendar] WHERE dateadd(dd, 0, datediff(dd, 0, DayDate)) = " + date
```

Or if using SQL Server 2008 you can do:

```
"SELECT DayNo FROM [Calendar] WHERE cast(DayDate As Date) = " + date
```